# Quick load data from CSV to List [Java]

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I have ca. 500.000 records in few columns in CSV file.

`ID | property1 | property2 | property3 | property4`

I need to load this data into ArrayList of Object. ID isn't unique. Every new ID  requires new instance of class `ID`, rest are instances of different class `Foo`. 
When I read CSV and find ID, which already occurred i need instance of class `ID`. What is the fastest way to do it? I try to use HashSet or HashMap (then searching in List take ca. 5 minutes) and lambda expressions as well (ca. 6 min). I can't use a database.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is pretty broad, and it would perhaps be clearer if you provided a minimal example and asked specific questions about it, such as where the bottlenecks might be, or how to accomplish something specific that you'd like to do. Please try to make your question more specific. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read the file into a `Map<String, List<String[]>>` Most of the time will be spend creating the Strings for the record.

This shouldn't take more than a few seconds to read depending on the length of each line, and lookup will be sub-micro-second.

You could just record the starting position of each line and parse them if you actually need them.

Here is an example using Stream.

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("file.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
    pw.println("ID" + i / 2 + " | property1 | property2 | property3 | property4");
pw.close();

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
Pattern BAR = Pattern.compile(" *[|] *");
Map<String, List<String[]>> collect = Files.lines(Paths.get("file.txt"))
        .map(line -> BAR.split(line))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(l -> l[0]));
long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
System.out.println("Took "+time/1e3+" seconds");
```

This prints

```
Took 4.028 seconds
```

This is running on an ultra-book.

Running concurrently sped it up a little

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
Pattern BAR = Pattern.compile(" *[|] *");
Map<String, List<String[]>> collect = Files.lines(Paths.get("file.txt"))
        .parallel()
        .map(line -> BAR.split(line))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(l -> l[0]));
long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
System.out.println("Took "+time/1e3+" seconds");
```

prints

```
Took 2.589 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks, I try to do this. I thought that most of time is spending on creating new instance of new ID_Object (I think there is ca. 60.000 objects to create, the rest are properties of this ID). ID is a class and properties can be String, so when I create objects in loop it takes up to 6 min!

Comment: @caesar_ try using parallel stream. This can help if you have more cores than I do.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter, I'll try and I'll let you know if I manage this